Kerberos authentication working for Chrome, Edge, Opera, and Brave, but not Firefox
Firefox (129.0.2) displays the following:
401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.
I have tried various combinations of setting and not setting the following in Firefox:

network.negotiate-auth.trusted-uris
network.negotiate-auth.delegation-uris
network.auth.use-sspi

For the URI settings I have tried both .domainname.domainextension and https://servicename.domainname.domainextension
In Windows 10 Control Panel -> Internet Options, the site is in "Trusted sites" using a domain wildcard, and also "Local intranet" and both "Automatic logon" and "Enable Integrated Windows Authentication" are enabled. I suspect those setting aren't relevant since other browsers are authenticating without error or prompt, but calling this out to show that I've covered that base.
The web service is served by IIS 10.0 on Windows Server 2022 and the authentication provider list only includes Negotiate, but I don't believe this issue has anything to do with IIS or its configuration as, again, other browsers are authenticating without error or prompt.
Anything else to check?
Thank you for any guidance you can offer.
Additional information as requested in comments:
about:logging with negotiateauth:5 while network.auth.use-sspi=true (default)
[Parent 6380: Main Thread]: D/negotiateauth   service = servicename.domainname.domainextension
[Parent 6380: Main Thread]: D/negotiateauth   using negotiate-sspi
[Parent 6380: Main Thread]: D/negotiateauth   nsAuthSSPI::Init
[Parent 6380: Main Thread]: D/negotiateauth Using SPN of [HTTP/hostname.domainname.domainextension]
[Parent 6380: Main Thread]: D/negotiateauth AcquireCredentialsHandle() succeeded.
[Parent 6380: BgIOThreadPool #14]: D/negotiateauth nsHttpNegotiateAuth::GenerateCredentials() [challenge=Negotiate]
[Parent 6380: BgIOThreadPool #14]: D/negotiateauth entering nsAuthSSPI::GetNextToken()
[Parent 6380: BgIOThreadPool #14]: D/negotiateauth InitializeSecurityContext: continue.
[Parent 6380: BgIOThreadPool #14]: D/negotiateauth   Sending a token of length 2702
[Parent 6380: BgIOThreadPool #14]: D/negotiateauth nsHttpNegotiateAuth::GenerateCredentials() [challenge=Negotiate]
[Parent 6380: BgIOThreadPool #14]: D/negotiateauth entering nsAuthSSPI::GetNextToken()
[Parent 6380: BgIOThreadPool #14]: D/negotiateauth InitializeSecurityContext failed [rc=-2146893048:]

about:logging with negotiateauth:5 while network.auth.use-sspi=false
[Parent 6380: Main Thread]: D/negotiateauth   service = servicename.domainname.domainextension
[Parent 6380: Main Thread]: D/negotiateauth   using negotiate-gss
[Parent 6380: Main Thread]: D/negotiateauth entering nsAuthGSSAPI::nsAuthGSSAPI()
[Parent 6380: Main Thread]: D/negotiateauth Fail to load gssapi library
[Parent 6380: Main Thread]: D/negotiateauth entering nsAuthGSSAPI::Init()

IIS normal logging (inetpub\logs\LogFiles)
s-sitename s-computername s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs-version cs-host sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status
W3SVC1 s-computername s-ip GET / - 443 - c-ip HTTP/2 servicename.domainname.domainextension 401 2 5
W3SVC1 s-computername s-ip GET / - 443 - c-ip HTTP/1.1 servicename.domainname.domainextension 401 2 5
W3SVC1 s-computername s-ip GET / - 443 - c-ip HTTP/1.1 servicename.domainname.domainextension 401 1 3221226331

IIS Failed Request Tracing (inetpub\logs\FailedReqLogFiles) with tracing on 400-499 status codes
from trace files 1 and 2 related to a single request
MODULE_SET_RESPONSE_ERROR_STATUS IIS Web Core 401.2
from trace file 3 related to the same request
MODULE_SET_RESPONSE_ERROR_STATUS WindowsAuthenticationModule 401.1

The message you received indicates that the account is authenticated, but not authorized. "Credentials  supplied". You may want to try about:logging and see if there is anything useful for authentication there. Also if you setup an http url you can use a packet capture to confirm the http authentication header is sent and the type of authentication used.

401 means unauthenticated.  403 means the request was authenticated but access was denied.  Yet IIS makes it ambiguous by conflating the two in the error text. :(


Are you using DoH in Firefox? If so, disable it and try again. 2) If you look at the requests via Firefox DevTools, does it show the Authorization header being sent? 3) If it is not sent, go to about:logging and enable logging for the negotiateauth:5 module, then try again and report the results.


@u1686_grawity 1) no. 2&3) see logging included in edited question. currently looking into "Fail to load gssapi library", but haven't yet found a clear cause or path forward for Windows machines

That message means it's trying to find libgssapi either from MIT KfW or from Heimdal Kerberos – in most cases you won't have those installed on Windows, and you should be using the native SSPI instead (use-sspi=true). Does HTTP/hostname.domainname.domainextension look correct as the SPN of your IIS server?

@u1686_grawity ok, will leave SSPI setting set to true (default) - i have seen mixed information about it in my research, so i've been trying it both ways each time. the SPN looks good and i've confirmed that the SPNs are in place for the domain account that the Application Pool is using

The name that you were connecting to in the URL, the host name, is that different from the service principal name?

@GregAskew we generally use servicename.domainname.domainextension which points to hostname.domainname.domainextension, but even when using hostname.domainname.domainextension directly the same error is encountered. both are registered SPNs on the domain account that the Application Pool is using

If you aren't able to get a capture, does developer mode show an authentication header? If so, it will show you if it is Kerberos or NTLM. Normally Kerberos authentication is simple, the complicated issues typically occur with delegation or weird topologies. But the actual auth at the front end should be trivial. Also there should be audit events on the web server that shows the authentication failure and credentials, same for the IIS logs.

@GregAskew Response: WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate | Request: Authorization: Negotiate string. It's my understanding that Negotiate prioritizes Kerberos first and then falls back on NTLM if Kerberos is unavailable, but in this case my guess is that the NTLM prompt is not showing up because Kerberos is available, Firefox just isn't completing the authentication process properly like the other browsers for some reason. IIS logging information added to "Additional information" section of question

If the authentication header begins with a "Y", it is Kerberos. If it begins with a "T", it is NTLM.

@GregAskew it's a Y

That's definitely a Kerberos token. For an account with presumably a ticket of 2,700 something.  What groups does an account need to be a member of to access this site?

@GregAskew there is an AD group that restricts access and my account is a member of that group. also, just a reminder, Chrome, Edge, Opera, and Brave are all working without error/prompt, so i wouldn't think the issue would be server-side (configuration or authorization)

Can you see what is in the header? The PAC payload is internally encrypted and that is fine and probably 99% of the payload. I'm curious how the other parts of the token are formatted, like the UPN or domain\username. console.log(new Buffer(req.headers.authorization.split(" ")[1], 'base64').toString())

@GregAskew aside from DOMAINNAME.DOMAINEXTENSION{encrypted-string}HTTPhostname.domainname.domainextension, the rest comes out encrypted. i suspect that the {encrypted-string} part i've redacted is \username, recalling a distant memory i have where i had seen the full AD domain called out like that before the username instead of it being the more common short version (ad-domain\username)
